# Drop-down menu links with Target?

Tags: javascript, select, hyperlink

How can I use this:

```
<select name="menu1">
<option value="http://www.espn.com">ESPN</option>
<option value="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</option>
<option value="http://www.abcnews.com">ABC</option>
<option value="http://www.cbsnews.com">CBS</option>
<option value="http://www.foxnews.com">FOX</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
urlmenu.onchange = function() {
window.open(  this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
};
</script>
```

and have those links open in an iframe name="viewbox" ?

Thank you much!

Comment: iframe inside the same page ?

Comment: yes. Also I am not using any submit button so it needs to load it when the option is selected on the select drop down.

Comment: its possible in jquery check my answer

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
    urlmenu.onchange = function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById( 'iframe_id' );
    iframe.src = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value ;
    };
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.getElementById("viewbox");
el.setAttribute('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<select id="my_slect">
<option value="http://www.espn.com">ESPN</option>
<option value="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</option>
<option value="http://www.abcnews.com">ABC</option>
<option value="http://www.cbsnews.com">CBS</option>
<option value="http://www.foxnews.com">FOX</option>
</select>
<iframe id="ifr"></iframe>
```

**Script**

```
$('#my_select').change(function() {
var url = $('#my_select :selected').val();
     $('#ifr').attr('src', url); 
    });
```